# Normal Text in Google Sheets is absent. How to enable?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Where has Google hidden `Normal Text` in Google Sheets? It is present in Google Docs but is absent in Google Sheets:

G Docs:

[image]

G Sheets. There is anything under the menu except `Normal Text`:

[image]

When I copy/paste from GDocs it doesn't paste `Normal Text`. How to enable `Normal Text` in GSheets?

Comment: I guess the question is - what is normal?

Comment: What would you expect to be in that menu? Spreadsheets have no concept of title, subtitle, or heading.

Answer (score 1):

Normal Text is a text style and the drop down button shown is a built-in feature of Google Documents. Google Sheets doesn't have that a built-in feature.

One alternative is to use Google Apps Script to format cells and add custom menus to make it easier to apply them but requires to know a bit of programming.

An easier alternative is to use a Google Sheets add-on like [Styles](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/styles/nkhhmdlcfanccpjadngacgjgecfbheje?utm_source=permalink). You can look for this and other addons at the [Addon Store](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create?addon_store)